# Interesting vector space connected with eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

First of all if anyone knows the name of this space please edit my title. The second thing is that I'd ask for hints or ideas rather than answers.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T$, we define $V_\lambda^k = \{v \in V| T(v) = \lambda v+ u \in V_\lambda^{k-1}\}$ and $V_\lambda^0 = \{0_V\}$. So now the following should be proven:

If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are distinct eigenvalues, then $V_\lambda^k \cap V_\mu^l = \{0_V\}$ for every $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$.

For each eigenvalue $\lambda$, there is a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V_\lambda^{i} = V_\lambda^k$ for all $i \ge k$.

My attempt for the first part: 
First fix an $l$ and proceed by induction on $k$, base case is $k=0$ and it proves itself basically. Now we assume that the proposition holds for all $k>0$ and we consider the $k+1$ case. Then we take $v\in V_\lambda^{k+1}$ and assume that $T(v) = \lambda v + u = \mu v + u'$ but now as both $\lambda v$ and $u$ are in $V_\lambda^k$ then so is their sum, but by our assumption the sum is also in $V_\mu^l$, contradicting the inductive step of the proof.

I feel like this is a bit shaky at best and completely wrong at worst so any correction/suggestion is appreciated.

For the second thing I really have no constructive ideas so I need help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not follow the step where you write "... now as both $\lambda v$ and $u$ are in $V_{\lambda}^{k}$ ..."

As for the hint: Note that $x\in V_{\lambda}^k$ if and only if $(T-\lambda I)^kv=0$. Also, the polynomials $(x-\lambda)^k$ and $(x-\mu)^l$ are relatively prime unless $\lambda = \mu$.

Comment: Just to clarify the step: I have already proven that $V_\lambda^1$ is actually just a set of eigenvectors and I have proven that if $i<j$ then $V_\lambda^i \subset V_\lambda^j$, and thus I thinkt that $\lambda v$ is in $V_\lambda^k$ and also $u$ is in $V_\lambda^k$ by the definition of $V_\lambda^{k+1}$.

Comment: @TdotA You picked $v\in V_\lambda^{k+1}$. Then you infer $\lambda v\in V_{\lambda}^k$, whcih means that $v\in V^{k}_\lambda$. So basically you have somehow shown that $V^{k+1}_\lambda\subseteq V^k_\lambda$. This is inference is incorrect.